# gnome-terminal new tab within exact same path

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I'm using gnome-terminal and open multiple tabs for the same path. The behavior of gnome-terminal is to change to the real (canonical) path rather than the exact original path.

E.g. a new tab opened in `/home/user/data/project` will be in `/mnt/data/project` if `/home/user/data` is a symlink to `/mnt/data`.

In this case, it is not much an issue, but I have some weirder paths :
`/cifs/project -> /home/user/.gvfs/partage on server/organisation/OU/projects/project`
and I the latter doen't look great on my prompt.

So, the question is : is there a way to open a new tab in the exact same path, rather than in the realpath, of the previous tab ?

Comment: I didn't find the answer yet. There isn't one, most probably. I guess I should look into the code.