# How to preserve path in a new tab in the gnome terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnome, debian-wheezy

At work I am using Ubuntu GNU/Linux 14.04. When I open a new tab in the gnome terminal, the working directory of the new shell is the same as in the terminal where I have pressed <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-T</kbd>.

At home I have Debian Wheezy, and here the default behaviour is to open the new shell in my home directory. I cannot find any documentation as to how to change this behaviour: I would like to have the Ubuntu behaviour on Debian.

Is this feature configurable at all or is it hard-coded, with different versions providing different behaviours? I have read the documentation and searched for a question on stack exchange but I could not find any information.

**EDIT**

I have looked into my .bashrc and indeed there was some complicated setup that ended up changing / resetting the path. So, I have come one step further but I still have one problem, which is illustrated in [this still unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/452350/gnome-terminal-new-tab-within-exact-same-path): if the path I am in uses some symbolic link, then the new shell uses the canonical path. Is there a known fix for this problem?

Comment: There is probably a difference between the various .profile or .bashrc. I would definitely look there.

Comment: @T0xicCode no, it's not. This is a gnome-terminal configuration question, not a matter of which `PATH` is set where.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I have not tried this myself because I don’t experience this problem; of course feel free to edit this answer if changes are necessary.

This is reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1193993%20Ubuntu%20Gnume%20bug%20#1193993) in Ubuntu Gnome, but I’m not surprised it also affects Debian. The solution appears to be adding `. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh` to the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (depending on whether you use Bash or ZSH).

Note that if you already have a `PROMPT_COMMAND` set in Bash, this will replace it; I believe in that case you need to set your custom `PROMPT_COMMAND` after the added line, and in there be sure to call `__vte_prompt_command`. Again, though, I have not tried this and some experimentation may be required.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, there is no file `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` on my system (Debian Wheezy).

Comment: I believe [this](https://github.com/GNOME/vte/blob/master/src/vte.sh) is the right file. I’m surprised it’s not supplied by GNOME terminal or one of its dependencies.

You might just want to put it in your user directory instead of `/etc/profile.d`, in case something else does supply it. I don’t know how Debian would deal with that.

Comment: Ok, found it. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem: my new shell is opened in `/local/home/giorgio` instead of `/home/giorgio`.